# Select xml nodes when sibling elements text node equals given value

Tags: xml, xpath, soap, soapui

**The following is a SOAP answer:**

```
   <dep:deposit>
       <dep:agreementData>
          <dm:ReferenceId>634_24570</dm:ReferenceId>
          <dm:status>
             <dm:code>STCLOSEOUT</dm:code>
             <dm:name>STCLOSEOUT</dm:name>
          </dm:status>
          <dm:code>133</dm:code>
          <dm:amount>5000</dm:amount>
          <dm:currency>EUR</dm:currency>
          <dm:documentDate>2015-12-11</dm:documentDate>
          <b:refer>3013011512126177799</b:refer>
          <b:product>
             <dm:code>3.7.1.EU</dm:code>
             <dm:name>Deposit EUR new</dm:name>
          </b:product>
          <b:department>
             <dm:code>301</dm:code>
          </b:department>
          <b:dateFrom>2015-12-11</b:dateFrom>
          <b:dateTo>2016-12-11</b:dateTo>
          <b:deaClient>
             <dm:code>0300.000306</dm:code>
          </b:deaClient>
          <b:balanceDep>
             <dm:code>301</dm:code>
          </b:balanceDep>
          <b:serviceDep>
             <dm:code>301</dm:code>
          </b:serviceDep>
          <b:salesDep>
             <dm:code>301</dm:code>
          </b:salesDep>
          <b:arrestFl>0</b:arrestFl>
          <dep:depoTermTU>12.0</dep:depoTermTU>
          <dep:depoTermTimeType>M</dep:depoTermTimeType>
          <dep:lockFl>0</dep:lockFl>
       </dep:agreementData>
    </dep:deposit>
```

Where the `status/code` of the `deposit` element can get different values as:

```
      <dm:status>
         <dm:code>STCLOSEOUT</dm:code>
         <dm:name>STCLOSEOUT</dm:name>
      </dm:status>
```

> How to use XPATH to get `dm:ReferenceId` with a specific status code,
>   for example, `STCLOSEOUT`. I want to use in SOAPUI test, Transfer
>   properties.

I will be grateful for the help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following xpath query:

```
//dm:status/dm:code[text()='STCLOSEOUT']/../../dm:ReferenceId
```

Description:

- for any `dm:status` element
- select the `dm:code` child with text node equalling `STCLOSEOUT` (or whatever code you want)
- go up twice to `dep:agreementData` and return the `dm:ReferenceId`

Demo: http://xpather.com/alhDD360